# I want to show same ID data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't get the logic to my problem. I have a database like this.

```
   ID      |     Offense     |    Remarks  
   003          No Id              Community service
   020          No Id              Community service
   012          No Id              Community service
   003          No Id              Community service
   003   Not in proper uniform     Community service
```

Now I want to show the Offense with the same ID like "003". And I want to show it in HTML like this.

```
 ID             Offense                Remarks
003             No ID              Community Service
003     not in proper uniform      Community Service.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM <table> GROUP BY ID, Offense;
```

You should refer to - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: For that use should fetch this data using `php` and then display it to `html`.

Answer (score 1):

use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM ....
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Query would be :

```
SELECT ID, DISTINCT Offense, Remarks FROM youtable WHERE ID = '03'
```